# Android gallery view library that support infinite loading or paging

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview, android-library

I want to have an Android gallery view library like: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

But like most of the other opensource libraries, is that, they don't support paging or infinite loading  - i.e. if I have more than 1K photos, I don't want to load at once. It would be the best if I can load them automatically, or even manually paging is fine.

For my use case, the list of photo is called from an API like the following, e.g.

```
http://example.com/get_photo.php?start=0&size=50
http://example.com/get_photo.php?start=50&size=50
..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have some meta data in your api that has the total count of the images, the current offset.
Check the the total count and the current offest in your scroll listener of  the listview or gridview and fetch data accordingly.